# How to Hide modified by in the document properties of IBM Lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

Hi does anyone know how to hide the "Modified by:" in the document property of IBM Notes? I made a simple IBM notes application but I want to protect identity of the person who created or modified the document. I know it is possible because one of my colleague already done this in the past but she's no longer connected to us.

Here's a screen shot

[image: Document Properties]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mark the form as Anonymous on Form properties:

[image]

Comment: That does it! Thank you!! Sorry that was very beginner type of question Thanks!